# How to Save Bearer Token for future Use using RestSharp

Tags: rest, api, testing, restsharp

Im a relative noob to automated testing - currently, I'm using Postman to generate RestSharp code for API requests in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Esentially, I'm creating a basic unit test, then plopping in the code to execute the test

What I need to know is this - is it possible for me in my tests to first do a login call and SAVE my bearer token in order to use in in all subsequent calls - in postman, this is easy because I can just set an environmental variable that pulls it in.

So essentially, what I need to do is make a login call to return the bearer token
save the bearer token, then use that token in the subsequent calls I make

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit late, but here is how I does it:

Use RestSharps `JwtAuthenticator`.  Get your access token the way you already do. Next create the `JwtAuthenticator` and finally use that authenticator in your RestSharp calls:

```
var accessToken = GetAccessToken();  // Does what ever is required to get the acces token
Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(accessToken);

...

var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = Authenticator;

...

// All requests will be correctly authenticated
client.Execute(requestA);
client.Execute(requestB);
client.Execute(requestC);

....
```